# Single terminal command to display resource usage

Tags: command-line, monitoring

I can't find way to monitor a single Linux terminal command.

I want to monitor this command:

```
php index.php parse
```

The problem is this process works too quickly to get the pid, so I hope there is something like this:

```
singlecommandmonitor php index.php parse
```

Where `singlecommandmonitor` is software which monitors ram, cpu, etc. usage and `php index.php parse` is the command that I want to monitor. It should work similar to `sudo`, but instead of giving root permissions it should monitor resources.

Comment: You mean the process finishes too quickly for you to manually get the pid? So you'd like to run a process, but rather than seeing output from that process, you'd see top for that process?

Comment: Yes I need top of that process. The command runs for few seconds so it is difficult to get its pid and then run top -p

Comment: `\time -v php index.php parse` does something similar, but it would be better if it will be more like top -p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least if you're launching the command in a bash shell, you might be able to use the internal variable `$!` which returns the PID of the last background job e.g.

```
php index.php parse & top -p $!
```

Comment: Alternatively: [`pidstat -p $!`](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat)